# Are there benefits in producing a .NET 6.0 version of a .NET Standard 2.0 library?

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0

If I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library project that is being consumed by a .NET 6.0 console project, are there any performance benefits if I also instruct the compiler to produce a .NET 6.0 version of the library?

I don't plan to use any functionality available on .NET 6.0, I just want to know if the .NET 6.0 version receives extra-love from the compiler.

Comment: I was wondering about this question in a more general sense: If I have a solution with 200 .NET Standard/.NET FW projects, do I need to upgrade all of them or just the startup project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asked the same thing on Twitter, and was fortunate enough to receive feedback from reputed experts [Bartosz Adamczewski](https://bio.link/bartosza), [Immo Landwerth](https://immo.landwerth.net/), [Jared Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) and [Lucas Trzesniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski)

Here is the [question link](https://twitter.com/sgorozco/status/1484284461197967364).

Here are the most relevant bits of info you can extract from the original Twitter thread:

> What you might gain is better IL, so things like strings and certain
> other things are handled better by the front-end compiler C# and
> better IL is generated, this, in turn, could provide better codegen in
> JIT - Bartosz Adamczewski

> @jaredpar  can correct me but for the most part the code gen isn’t
> depending on the target framework, except for cases where the code gen
> users specific APIs, which is rare. - *Immo Landwerth*

> That is correct. At the compiler level there is no concept of target
> frameworks, there are just references. Hence all decisions about code
> gen are based on the API in the references. - *Jared Parsons*

> In the case of .NET 6, you'll get access to some new APIs such as
> `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler`, so for instance all of your string
> interpolation expressions ($"...") will get a perf boost just by
> targeting net6.0. Also, there are new method overloads such as
> `StringBuilder.Append` that take string interpolation handlers as
> parameters. **Your string interpolation expressions will target these
> instead when targeting net6.0, and your code will allocate less than
> on other targets. So yes, in some cases, your code will get more
> love by the compiler if you add a net6.0 target**  - *Lucas
> Trzesniewski*